# ¿Cómo crear un archivo que almacene variables date correctamente?

Tags: python, python-3.x

¡Hola!
Me mencionaron una respuesta a mi anterior pregunta que funciona correctamente, hasta que...
Cuando intento almacenar la variable en el archivo y leo este archivo, la variable se nombra como "datetime.date", provocando que al importarla me de el error "NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined."

EJEMPLO:

```
#En mi archivo1 creo una variable y la guardo en otro archivo
variable_x = date(2020, 05, 09)

with open("variables.py", 'w') as archivo:
    archivo.write(f"from datetime import date\n")
    archivo.write(f"variable_x = {repr(variable_x)}\n")
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, el archivo se crea y almacena las variables, sólo que ahora tiene un prefijo diferente...

```
#NOMBRE_ARCHIVO: varibles.py (recalcando el nombre)
from datetime import date
variable_x = datetime.date(2020, 05, 09)
```

Lo importante es que **necesito trabajarlo como date, no como datetime**
¿Alguna idea para solucionarlo? ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usando la variable de forma simple tipo:

```
from datetime import date

strDate = '2/4/18'

print (strDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes importar primero la biblioteca, y luego lo que quieres usar de ella:

```
import datetime
from datetime import date
```

Seguramente sea eso anterior que te comenté. Dado lo otro: posiblemente, eso que te arroja es algo parecido a esto

```
>>> objDate = datetime.strptime(strDate, '%m/%d/%y')
>>> objDate
 datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 4, 0, 0)
```

Y si eso lo quieres convertir en string:

```
>>> datetime.strftime(objDate,'%b %d, %Y')
 'Feb 04, 2018'
```

Lo cual no está del todo mal porque python luego entenderá que está trabajando con un fecha. Pero existen maneras de convertir eso en un string, o en algo más fácil de utilizar.

Te dejaré a continuación algunas páginas que seguramente podrían ayudar.

https://blog.ipswitch.com/es/formato-de-fecha-en-python
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html
https://python-para-impacientes.blogspot.com/2014/02/operaciones-con-fechas-y-horas.html

Espero haberte ayudado en algo.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el método `__repr__` al que llama `repr` genera la representación de la clase (correctamente por otro lado) mostrando toda la cadena de namespaces de la que proviene. La solución es tan simple como modificar el import, importando el módulo y no la clase:

```
from datetime import date


variable_x = date(2020, 5, 9)

with open("variables.py", 'w') as archivo:
    archivo.write(f"import datetime\n")
    archivo.write(f"variable_x = {repr(variable_x)}\n")
```

Mencionas ("necesito trabajarlo como date, no como datetime"), pero `varible_x` sigue siendo un objeto `date`, `datetime`  en `datetime.date` hace referencia al módulo, módulo al que pertenecen tanto la clase `date` (`datetime.date`) como la clase `datetime` (`datetime.datetime`).  En ningún momento se ha cambiado el tipo de la variable. Si quieres comprobarlo haz ésto:

```
from datetime import date


variable_x = date(2020, 5, 9)
print(type(variable_x))
```

observarás como te imprime:

```
<class 'datetime.date'>
```